# QGIS DXF contours with elevation

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, dxf

I have followed all instructions from [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxCxBREEqG0&feature=emb_logo).

1. Create contours and show elevation values
2. Open GRASS plugin on QGIS - create new mapset and choose the `"import loaded vector"` command from GRASS and choose your contour layer
3. `v.to.3d.attr` (Performs a transformation of 2D vector features to 3D to height based on attribute)

Once I hit step 3 QGIS crashes both 3.10 and 3.12 versions but something that's very essential is that the contour vector layer created from step 2 does NOT have any elevation data and I have been told that causes QGIS to crash at step 3.

Also, after running step two the new contour vector layer has a question mark next to it saying that the layer has no CSR set.

I double click on the question mark and set the same coordinate system reference as the one for the TIFF file which is WGS 84 EPSG 4326 and then proceed to step 3.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You can use Processing Toolbox v.to.3d is available there, nowadays it is preffered. I've made a quick test it works, and no need to import data to GRASS database.

Comment: @Zoltan

The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:\Users\IvanT\AppData\Local\Temp/processing_9207e5deb65847f5afda126de6b80080/38d27d03e2f449038d3d5ee77df3fc2d/output.gpkg</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm...................................




I have executed what you suggested and in the drop down menu "name of attribute column used for height I have selected "ELEV", have not changed any of the other settings... Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you are on windows you have to use QGIS with GRASS from programs, I'm on Linux (Ubuntu). If you can share your data I can try on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

v3.18 was crashing as well, but I had success with 3.16.
I am also getting the no CSR ?mark, but just ignore it.